# File exists but Colab says no such file found

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I mounted the files from google drive correctly with the following code.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
base_path = "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Colab\ Notebooks/data"
CAPUCHIN_FILE = os.path.join(base_path, 'Parsed_Capuchinbird_Clips', 'XC3776-3.wav')
print(CAPUCHIN_FILE) # prints /content/gdrive/MyDrive/Colab\ Notebooks/data/Parsed_Capuchinbird_Clips/XC3776-3.wav
```

My `ls` command proves that the file exists.

However, when trying to open it with Tensorflow-io, Colab notebook thinks it is not there.

What is happening here?

[image]

I have tried kernel restart and forced unmount.
Still doesn't work.

Comment: fix your backslash..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a backslash in your `base_path`. The ls command and Python's string handling might escape that backslash differently.

```
base_path = "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/data"
```

Comment: Oh I see. I never thought string handling would be different for each language framework etc.
 Thank for pointing it out.